# Android: Is there a PC port?

Tags: android, operating-system, x86

Is it possible to have Android running on `x86` computers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like someone is working on it... http://www.androidx86.org/

Answer (score 1):

Yup, there's already an [image you can install on an Eee](http://virtuallyshocking.com/2008/12/20/building-android-for-the-asus-eeepc-701/).

Answer (score 0):

The other way of course is to run an Android emulator. The Android SDK ships with an emulator that can run all the different versions of the OS. It is using qemu for the emulation of the ARM processor architecture.